# check array value exists in another array or not

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 fields in a table

```
filed1               | filed2
ahmed,join,maya,omar | omar,maya
```

I get data by 2 array , I want check if Each value in $array1 the present in $array2 or not

in my case : if `$array1[omar]` present in `$array2` or not , if `$array1[maya]` present in `$array2` or not .. elc

That's my code , not worked ...What's wrong in it ?

```
$query = $db->query_first("SELECT * FROM table ");
$array1 = explode(",",$query[filed1]);
$array2 = explode(",",$query[filed2]);

foreach($array1 as $value)
{
    if (in_array($value,$array2))
    {
        //true
    }else{
        //false
    }
}
```

output of array1 :

```
Array ( [0] => maya [1] => omar [2] => ahmed [3] => join)
```

output of array2 :

```
Array ( [0] => omar [1] => maya )
```

I have known the cause of the problem, not in the code ... Content of the field at the base value of each line separately So used str_replace to delete the line

```
$query = $db->query_first("SELECT * FROM table ");
$array1 = explode(",",$query[filed1]);
$array1 = str_replace("\n","",$array1);
$array2 = explode(",",$query[filed2]);
$array2 = str_replace("\n","",$array2);

foreach($array1 as $value)
{
    if (in_array($value,$array2))
    {
        //true
    }else{
        //false
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i edit it , my code not work

Comment: What exactly not work?

Comment: Show the results of `var_dump($array1);` and `var_dump($array2);`

Comment: You're not checking to see if your $query was successful. Is `$array1` or `$array2` populated?

Comment: @u_mulder okay , Results always come `false`

Comment: Look at using a function like [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Comment: @Mark Baker how i used it `array_intersect() `

Comment: @omar - you start by reading the docs that I've linked

Comment: @Jay Blanchard , iam sure my `$query` was successful

Comment: var_dump($query); what does it give you? If you have the values as you say, your code works fine.

Comment: Really sure? Without error checking I would not be so sure.

Comment: @Hammerstein yeah `var_dump($query);` it's give me a values

Comment: @Jay Blanchard , yeah Without any error , iam sure For this I am surprised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MarkBaker said, you want to use **[array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)**:

> array_intersect() returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are present in all the arguments. Note that keys are preserved.

In your case:

```
$array1 = explode(",",$query[filed1]);
$array2 = explode(",",$query[filed2]);

$intersect = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

Since you asked, to check if this array is empty or not do the following:

```
if (empty($intersect))
    echo 'It is empty';
```

Comment: thnx for you edit , but that's not my question , i don't want check if `$intersect` empty or not , have contains or not , i want check if value `maya` exist in `array2` or not , and value `omar` exist in `array2` or not , elc ... and i have a problem i try to print  `$intersect` give me `Array ( )` , Knowing that when i print `$array1 ` and `$array2 ` give me a values like this , `Array ( [0] => maya [1] => omar [2] => ahmed [3] =>  join) ` and `Array ( [0] => omar [1] => maya ) ` .. i hope you understand my problem .

Comment: Can you use var_dump instead of print_r and edit you question with the result you obtain.

Comment: okay i edit my question , and i try `var_dump` give me `array(0) { }`

Comment: try this
`$array1 = Array ( 0 => 'maya', 1 => 'omar', 2 => 'ahmed', 3 => 'join');
$array2 = Array ( 0 => 'omar', 1 => 'maya' );
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);`

Comment: okay it's work `Array ( [0] => maya [1] => omar )` , why in my code not work ? `Quotation marks` or what and don't forget my problem is i want check : if `$array1[omar]` present in `$array2` or not , if `$array1[maya]` present in `$array2` or not .. elc ...check if Each value in $array1 the present in $array2 or not

Comment: You mean $array1[0], (because $array1[omar] does not exist) ?

Comment: well adam , how i ckeck by a `key` of a `value`, anyway to do waht i want `check if Each value in $array1 the present in $array2 or not ` , and why no result when i print `$intersect` in my code :(

Comment: This is what you want:
$array1 = Array ( 0 => 'maya', 1 => 'omar', 2 => 'ahmed', 3 => 'join');
$array2 = Array ( 0 => 'omar', 1 => 'maya' );

if (in_array($array1[0], $array2));
 echo $array1[0]." is in the first array<br />";
if (in_array($array1[1], $array2));
 echo $array1[1]." is in the first array";

Comment: sir , that's not good way to check .. by your way you must get all keys for all values than check one next one , i want ckeck value Automatically like you get all values ​​similar between tow arrays Automatically  `$intersect = array_intersect($array1, $array2);` , sorry your code not help me . thnx anyway !

Comment: if (count($intersect) == count($array2)) echo 'all value from array2 are in array1'

Comment: if you want check by key you can use `array_key_exists()` , i don't want to do all that to make simple check , i want simple way to easy `check if Each value in $array1 the present in $array2 or not`

Comment: That is really hard to understand what you really want, anyway I gave You a solution:`if (count($intersect) == count($array2)) echo 'all value from array2 are in array1'`

Comment: i said my problem but you cannot understand it , i don't want check `all value from array2 are in array1` , i said `check if Each value in $array1 the present in $array2 or not` - foucs on this word `Each value` not `all value`

Comment: like `if (in_array('omar',$array2))
{
echo 'found';
}else{
echo 'not found';
}
if (in_array('maya',$array2))
{
echo 'found';
}else{
echo 'not found';
}
if (in_array('join',$array2))
{
echo 'found';
}else{
echo 'not found';
}`

Comment: thnx .. I have known the cause of the problem, not in my code , Placed above the solution